# CSS Dropdown Transitions

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I'm a little bit lost on how to animate my dropdown menu with CSS only. Can you guys light me up here?

I've tried

```
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

but I can't hit the note where how to exactly do it. 
The sub-menu shows up but instantly without any transitions. Any help will be great.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  height: 100px;     
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
      <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    </div>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `display` property cannot be animated, because it either is one value, or it isn't, there's nothing in between. You rather want to transition the element's `opacity` property, by setting it to 0 by default and to 1 on hover, removing the `display: none;`. In addition to that, use `pointer-events: none` to prevent the invisible `.dropdown-content` element from intercepting any mouse events like hover or click, and set it to `pointer-events: all` when the parent element is hovered.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.dropdown-content {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  height: 100px;     
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 200px;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
           <div class="dropdown-content">
               <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
               <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
               <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
          </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```